# How to achieve high TPS in Microservices project in multiple datacentres?

Tags: java, oracle, microservices

I am working on **Microservices project where Transaction Per second (TPS)** is very high say **200 transactions/sec**. Now we've three data centers (DC-1, DC-2 and DC-3) on top of this DC we've AKAMAI level which load balance the request and its works like round robin.

Technologies used - Spring Boot, For inter-service communication RestTemplate

**Issue** - Assume one service request lands on DC-1 and create Order and its subsequent request comes on DC-2 to get the details about the created Order (Vice-versa and other combinations are also not working well). Then that request is not getting the order created because data replication process between database is not that fast and hence data is not syncing as fast as expected. Its not that performant, We're using Oracle-12 as database. Event golden gate is not working that fast.

What are the ways we can have a database replication? Or can we think of Redis implementation or Apache Kafka ? Will that be so performant to cater the 200 TPS request?

Can somebody share detailed insights if have done already since its a very often issue

Comment: 200 TPS is not really high. An average database should be able to handle that.

Comment: You may use [high availability](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/high-availability.html) options provided by the database itself, when vendor has already taken care of all the complexity of the infrastructure and managed distributed transactions internally with the native mechanism. Instead of building the system with high maintenance effort.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - Looks like GoldenGate replication is not that fast to cater the 200TPS in our org, it assume to be slow. What are the best practices that can cater this much?

Comment: Could you use [sharding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)) to avoid the need of the replication at all?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - How sharding can help to avoid cross datactre issues? Can you please though some light? I believe its very generic issue

Comment: Sharding maps the key e.g. the *order number* to a specific node (data center), so each order is stored only once and you need not to relicate. You may still want to full replicate say *customer* or *product* data as they are less dynamic. Check the above link and other resources.

Comment: Round robin requests that get async-replicated to databases in other DCs is not sensible if you expect to need to read the data you just inserted. What is the point of the 3 DCs? One DB can easily handle many times more than 200 transactions per second, why not just point all traffic to there, and have the other two DCs in case of disaster. Otherwise change your load balancing so that the node spoken to for data A is always DC-1 and data B is DC-2 etc (this is sharding but you can keep the async replication for DR)